# Are there bounds given for the strengthened Ramsey theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, logic, ramsey-theory, provability

The [Paris-Harrington theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem) says that a variant of the finite Ramsey theorem is not provable in Peano arithmetic, but it is [provable in stronger systems](https://mathoverflow.net/q/555).

The proof of the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem in ZFC is non-constructive, so given $n, k, m$ (see the wikipedia link) it doesn't tell us how to find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ for which the relevant statement $P(n, k, m, N)$ holds.

I am curious, are there any results that tell us the upperbound on $N$ given $n, k, m$? If not, is there a proof that this can't be done in Peano arithmetic or ZFC? If yes, what is the result and in what system is it proven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "Rapidly growing Ramsey functions" by Jussi Ketonen and Robert Solovay [Annals of Mathematics 113 (1981) pp/ 267--314].  If I remember correctly, the necessary size $N$ for the Paris-Harrington theorem is "just barely" beyond the order of growth attainable by provably recursive functions of PA.